# Bootstrap Validator: Validating dynamic radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying a dynamic input validation yet

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" value="1"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[0]" required>
<input type="radio" value="2"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[0]" required>
<input type="radio" value="3"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[0]" required>
```

//clones field

```
<input type="radio" value="1"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[1]" required>
<input type="radio" value="2"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[1]" required>
<input type="radio" value="3"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[1]" required>
```

//clones field

```
<input type="radio" value="1"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[2]" required>
<input type="radio" value="2"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[2]" required>
<input type="radio" value="3"  class="job_knowledge" name="job_knowledge[2]" required>
```

can't validate it when I try placing a:

**JS BOOTSTRAP VALIDATOR**

```
$('#evaluation_form').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            job_knowledge:{
                selector:'.job_knowledge',
                validators:{
                    notEmpty:{
                      message: "This field is required"
                    }
                }
              }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? or What you want to validate? post clearly

Comment: I'm trying to validate those radio inputs. It works when then clones don't exist but when cloning happens, it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please add some external link to the code of the bootstrap validator you use?

Comment: formvalidation.io/